# How to hide Windows Phone 8.1 app without having user press the back button

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, back

When handling `Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event, if `Handled` is not set to true, the app will be hidden and the phone will return to home screen.

Is there a way to achieve the same without having user press the back key?

Btw. I don't want to close/exit/terminate the app (which is not recommended by Microsoft), I just want to do whatever default BackPressed handling does.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to bring the homescreen without exiting the app is to pin a tile on the homescreen. It's probably not a practical solution.

Either way, what you're trying to do is contradictory with Windows Phone design concepts. The user must stay in control at all time. If the user wants to exit, he'll press the back button. If he wants to keep your application alive, he'll press the home button. If the user isn't able to exit your application even though he wants to, that will create frustration.

Comment: I want to adhere to Windows Phone design concepts. For consistency with other platforms my app has another back button in the main UI. I want it do to exactly the same thing as hardware back button does - go back to home screen. But I see no way of doing that.

Comment: throw an Exception propably the only way to do this. But you need to decide if it's good for you